# c program to allow user to change there already set 4 digit pin

Tags: c

1. Enter PIN and verify correct
2. Change PIN
3. Display the number of times the PIN was entered (i) Successfully (ii) 
   Incorrectly
4. Exit Program

I am having problems option 2 in the question above it is supposed to do the following:
If they select option 2, they should be allowed to change their PIN. the program should verify the original pin first. When they enter the new PIN, your program must verify the new PIN by asking the 
customer to re-enter this new PIN. This will verify that the new PIN entered 
is correct and no errors were made. If there are any differences and the 
verification fails, your program must display an appropriate error message 
and the original PIN should remain the same.

My problem arises when the user is entering their new pin, 1. the pin must be 4 digits long 2. If the user enters a pin wrong when entering a new pin, the original pin must remain the same. If they enter their new pin right then their new pin must change to that pin. I have posted the code i have so far for option 2.

If my question is not clear please ask me questions.

```
case 2:
      {
           //ask user to enter their current pin
           printf("Please enter your current pin \n");
           scanf("%d",&current_pin);


           if(current_pin != 1234)
           {
                //if pin entered is not the same as 1234-print error
                printf("Incorrect pin \n");
                unsuccessful ++;
                break;
           }//end if    

           else
            {
                successful++; 

                //ask user to enter new pin
                printf("Please enter your new pin: \n");
                scanf("%d",&new_pin);           

            } //end else

            //set new pin as the current pin
            current_pin = new_pin:      

            //check if pin is 4 digits long
            if(current_pin>999 && current_pin<10000)
            {
                //ask user to re enter their new pin
                printf("Please re-enter your new pin: \n");
                scanf("%d",&new_pin);

                printf("Your new pin is %d", new_pin);

                //set new pin as the current pin
                current_pin = new_pin:  
            }   

           else
            {
                printf("Incorrect entry- pin must be 4 digits and cannot start with a 0");                          
            }

                   new_pin=current_pin;

              break;
            }
```

I know this code is very sloopy i hope you can make sense of it. I know what i am trying to do but i can't do it.

****EDIT****
Ok i now understand that i have made some of you confused.  Maybe i should reword my question. And break it down into sections. And if it is easier i can post the full code for the program.

1. I want the user to enter their current pin which if the program is running for the first time has been assigned the value 1234. If the user has already gone through the process the current pin will now be the pin they have changed it to.
2. The pin new pin must be 4 digits
3. This might be pushing it but if the user enters a letter into my program it will go into an infinite loop, is there a simple way around this.

Comment: First thing I see is that if the user enters the new PIN incorrectly, you should exit the function. As it is, you drop through and set new_pin=current_pin;  !!!!  But, can you tell us what problem8s) you are actually having?

Comment: Is your switch statement contained in a loop? For a start you should be having something like while(current_pin != 1234) you ask the user to enter it again either until they decide to opt out or the number of unsuccessful attempts is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little odd:

```
   printf("Please enter your current pin \n");
   scanf("%d",&current_pin);
   if(current_pin != 1234)
   {
```

Is current_pin the value that stores the user's pin? If so you'll change it when you do scanf. Create a new variable to store the result. Something like this:

```
   int value;
   scanf("%d",&value);
   if(current_pin != value)
   {
```

You seem to be doing this a lot:

```
current_pin = new_pin:
```

I will admit I'm a bit confused as to whether the colon is a typo or does something I don't understand.

However, you shouldn't do this assignment until you have checked the value of the new pin

```
//check if pin is 4 digits long
if(new_pin>999 && new_pin<10000)
{
    int verified;
    //ask user to re enter their new pin
    printf("Please re-enter your new pin: \n");
    scanf("%d",&verified);

    if(verified == new_pin))
    {
        printf("Your new pin is %d", new_pin);

        //set new pin as the current pin
        current_pin = new_pin; // <--- This is the only place you assign to current_pin 
    }
    else
    {
        //tell the user there was an error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first if statment

```
if (current_pin != 1234)
```

You're comparing the current_pin to a constant value `1234`
Try using a variable instead of `1234` constant.

Answer (score 0):

You never checked if reentered newpin is same as newpin.